# how to retrieve the previous email template?

Tags: email-template

I recently changed the email template however i want to see my previous email template. Can anyone suggest on this how we can retrieve the previous email template?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

1. If your dev ops model is to make changes in a sandbox/scratch org and then deploy to source control before deploying onwards to PROD; then source control will have the prior version
2. If you made the change directly in PROD and have no source control for backup, then the best option is to hope that there is some legacy sandbox that was created from PROD at an earlier time that you can inspect and copy-past back into PROD